Having troubles deploying Angular 18 after upgrade from Angular 17 with ASP.NET Core 8.0 to Azure web app
I recently upgraded an ASP.NET Core 8.0 solution frontend from Angular 17 to 18. Locally the application runs and builds fine and is using Angular 18 as shown in the dev tools. Using Azure Devops, I am able to build the solution and the build step shows logs consistent with Angular 18. Then using Azure Devops, the deployment to our Azure Web App is successful and the Web App shows a deployment success.
However, when I open the deployed web app none of my changes have made it through and the dev tools show that it is still running Angular 17 on the front end. Is the web app possibly caching our old front-end?
Tried to deploy my Angular 18 & ASP.NET Core 8 solution.
Expected a successful deploy.

can you check angular.json diff during the upgrade? what was the builder and did it change after the upgrade

@Benjamin Pastern Have you checked your package.json in the Kudu console after deployment?

@BEnjamin Pastern Sometimes changes are reflected slowly; please try refreshing.

The solution was reverting my angular.json file back to the way it was pre-upgrade. When I ran ng update @angular/core@18 @angular/cli@18 the updater switch the builder from @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser to @angular-devkit/build-angular:application. This ran fine locally but the Azure Web App was not set up in a way to run with this configuration. As to why the Web App was still displaying the old angular front-end after a successful deploy of the new front-end I am not sure.
code change snip
